Initialize template of his own type
How could I explicitly initialize a template so that it takes an argument of its own type?
For example:
// header1.h
template<typename T>
class MyClass {};

// source1.cc
template class MyClass<MyClass<????>>;

Going deeper into the problem. I am trying to represent a function, for which I need to store the body of the function, so I came up with a vector.
The code looks like this:
// commons.h
template<class T>
class Function {
private:
const std::vector<T> body;
const std::string name;

public:
Function(std::string name, std::vector<T> body);
};


this is a basic representation that I'm trying to make, obviously I'm not storing parameters or return values ​​or anything like that

The vector will store other objects, where those objects can also be other functions (instances of Function)
Then when instantiating the template:
// commons.cc
template<typename T>
Function<T>::Function(
std::string name,
std::vector<T> body
): name(name), body(body) {}

template class Function<Function<???>>;

This is where I have the problem, from what you've told me, this is not possible (which I understand as @463035818_is_not_an_ai said, since infinite space would be needed)
Obviously I knew that the TypeScript generics system that I was used to, was not going to be the same. That's why I have a hard time understanding.
I hope this helps you understand my problem

This doesn't make sense logically.

what are you trying to achieve? This is a xy problem and I am certain that there is a different way for your actual problem. I suppose a level of indirection will do.

Note also that a template is not a type. You'll need to change the parameter to a template template parameter. Also this is not initialization.

It's called instantiation not intialization here.

I am more curious as why you think you need this. It makes no sense... It feels like you would start a kind of recursion with no end condition

MyClass<MyClass<int>> would be fine, but I think you want something else, but what exactly you want is not quite clear

the problem with this question is that wrong code, code that makes no sense, is not good to explain what you want. Broken code is just broken, it has no meaning. You need to explain to us what that line should be. Moreover you mix up terminology. As others mentioned, the template is instantiated not initialized and a template has no "its own type", a template is not a type. Perhaps some useage example could help to clarify.

@Pepijn Kramer also 463035818_is_not_an_ai
I want to make a vector that can store values ​​of a type that in turn can contain itself. More specifically, I want to represent the body of a function. For this, in the same body of the function there could be other functions, and so on recursively.
Sorry for some mistakes like: intialization instead of instantiation, im noobie with c++. Coming from TypeScript I'm too used to its type system and it's a bit difficult for me to adapt to a different way of writing generics.

" type that in turn can contain itself." that is not possible for the same reason. A type cannot possibly contain itself. If it would be possible the size of such a type would be infinite, because every instance contains another instance, which contains another one, which in turn contains another one, ad infinitum. As suggested above, you should tell us about the actual issue you are working on, not only about what you think makes a solution, because it doesnt

Unrelated to this issue, c++ templates are usually implemented in headers, not in .cpp files. One cannot instantiate a template without the implementation being present, declaration in the header is not enough.

... though you can have a type that contains a pointer to the same type

Your problem is thinking that a template is a type.  It is not, it is a recipe on how to make a type.  The T parameter is what differentiates one template instantiation from another.  There is now way to just make a MyClass.

@Raxabi Your comment does a decent job of explaining what you're trying to achieve: "I want to represent the body of a function. For this, in the same body of the function there could be other functions, and so on recursively." Please add that explanation to the question itself.

You could achieve this with a nested vector of the same type: struct S { std::vector<S> v; };

@Raxabi Do you know the code you want to represent at compile time? Then you might be able to do something like this. If you only know the data at runtime you would need some other recursive datastructure. E..g like cigien already states

"I need to store the body of the function..." Use a lambda.

Have you heard of std::function?

How to declare a vector of functions (lambdas)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai sure, but it turns out OP needs something very slightly weaker than what he wants.  He wants a type to store a vector of varants, with the variants including the type itself.  That is quite doable!

Your first "for example" is too small and should be removed because for the first example, with no class body or anything, you would just drop the template.  MyClass can refer to MyClass just like that without being a template.

Do you need template? what T should represent? class Function { private: const std::vector<Function> body;}; might be OK.

Have you tried a Y combinator?
Naming the template argument's category is tricky.  If you are ok with using non type template argument proxies, you can do
template<auto self>
class Foo;

and have decltype(self)::type be Foo.
Alternatively, we could pass a proxy template and have
template<auto proxy>
class Foo

with decltype(proxy(tag<Foo>)):;type be Foo.
The general problem of
template<class T>
class Foo;

with some type Foo<Z> having the property that Z = Foo<Z> in C++ is that every type has a guaranteed finite structure terminating with class, struct, and fundamental types.
Meanwhile Foo<Z> = Foo<Foo<Z>> = Foo<Foo<Foo<Z>>>…  - it does not terminate and cannot terminate given your restrictions.
That being the case, you can get many of the benefits by passing some type that in turn produces the type you use.  This can be used to make std functions like objects that return std functions like objects of the same type, for example. (Useful in state machine code).

It is impossible.
A specialization of a class template that contains itself as one of its template arguments (whether directly or as template argument of a template argument, recursively) is not valid and therefore also can't be instantiated at all, whether explicitly or implicitly.
Even worse, there exists no syntax to even refer to such a recursive specialization given that a program must have finite length.
